# Один Producer - Много Consumers C++

Tags: c++

1. 1 производитель должен генерировать данные с заданным темпом (например, 500 мс).
2. 10 потребителей должны получать одни и те же данные, но со своим индивидуальным темпом (от 500 мс до 10 с). И у них не должно быть конкуренции типа один получил, другие - нет.
3. Производитель и потребители должны работать в отдельных потоках (процессах?).

Вопрос, как лучше организовать взаимодействие производителя и потребителей?
а) Производитель отправляет всем вычисленные данные со своим темпом, а потребители пусть сами разбираются, использовать эти данные в данный момент или пропускать и ждать своего случая?
б) Потребители сами обращаются в нужное им время и запрашивают у производителя данные на нужный им момент?
Использовать для обмена потоки? Или разместить производителя и потребителей в разные процессы и применить IPC в виде pipes? Или обмен по сети?

Для платформы Windows, язык с++ (Qt, Visual Studio)

Comment: Т.к. продюсер про индивидуальный темп консьюмеров ничего не знает - лучше pull, чем push. С другой стороны, объективного ответа на ваши вопросы, грубо говоря, не существует, а вопросы с ответами, основанными на мнениях тут оффтоп)

Comment: Можно хоть в 1 потоке всё делать на coroutine. Только вот обычно такие мутные задачи даются преподавателем и он явно говорит разделённые процессы это или несколько потоков. А вообще лучший вариант это for (auto& data:data_storage) process_data(data); нет многопоточности, нет и проблем с ней.